# What is the best approach to migrate MySQL database between GCP Accounts?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, database-migration

I need to clone a MySQL database in one GCP to another GCP account.

The most obvious way I can think of is exporting MySQL and then importing it another account.

What are other alternatives?

Comment: What are your constraint? Can you shut down the database for a couple of hours?

Comment: Sorry I meant clone. Accidentally said I needed to update a clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Cloud SQL page in the console and chose `migrate data`. Here you have several cases of migration, and among them this one which match your requirement:

> - Google Cloud project to Google Cloud project
>
> Move an instance from another Google Cloud project into this one

You can choose to set this read replica as master (and thus to finish the migration), or you can keep the state of read replica and your clone will be always the image of your original project. Here the described steps:

> The Cloud SQL Migration Assistant will guide you through the following steps:
>
> - Providing details on your data source
> - Creating a Cloud SQL read replica
> - Synchronising the read replica with the source
> - Promoting the read replica to your primary instance (optional)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Export data to Cloud Storage in the source account**

Choose Cloud Storage export location, Format

> The SQL export process may take a long time (possibly an hour or more
>   for large instances). You will not be able to perform operations on
>   your instance for the entire duration of the export. Once begun, this
>   process cannot be canceled.

**2. Copy the exported dump file to destination account**

a. Create a  bucket

b. Edit bucket permissions

c. Add member

d. Enter the mail source account

e. Select Role

Copy the file from soure account to destination account :

```
gsutil mv gs://source/export gs://destination/export
```

If the dump file is to big use: Cloud Data Transfer

**3. Select Cloud SQL Migrate data**

Begin Migration

a. Choose Data Source Details: Name of data source, Public IP address of source, Port number of source, MySQL replication username, Password,

b. Create and configure a new Cloud SQL read replica of the external primary instance. Choose Read replica instance ID, Location, Region, Machine type, Storage type, Storage capacity, Import SQL dump from Google Cloud Storage

c. Data synchronization

d. Read replica promotion (optional)